# remove anchor elements added from the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding some html to div from sever side. I want to remove all anchor tags from that html but preserve their text when I am sending that html back to the server on the click of button.

Below is the Html I am adding to div from server:

```
<p>
    <strong><u>Database Decommission Notice – IMPORTANT NOTIFICATION</u></strong>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>FOLLOWING DATABASE(S) ARE SCHEDULED TO BE DECOMMISSIONED in 4 WEEKS </strong>
</p>

<p>
    <strong><a href="#">Why have you received this email?</a></strong>
</p>
<p>
    <a href="#">You are receiving this email as because you are an ITAO/ITAO delegate/CSM/CSM-1/key technical contact for database(s) that are scheduled to be decommissioned by 30. Below are the applications you have been identified.?</a>
</p>
```

Can someone please help to achieve this?

Edit: 
I just realized that I am not even able to select anchor tags. I am not sure if is it because I added this complete html from the server side. I tried this but it just doesn't go inside loop.

```
$('#btnSaveTemplate').click(function () {
            var emailbody = $('#divEmailBody');

            var atag = emailbody.children('a[href=#');
            $(atag).each(function () {
                alert($(this).contents());
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery via:

```
$('a[href="#"]').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: I tried that but anchor tags still remain. I am adding this entire html to div (div is runat=server) from server side (asp.net code behind)

Comment: if you do everything at client side it will definitely work man!

Comment: So then what's the problem? Where else are you running jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
 $('a').replaceWith(function(){
       return $(this).contents();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex in Asp.NET as follow:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"<a\b[^>]+>([^<]*(?:(?!</a)<[^<]*)*)</a>", "$1")
```